# How to find a match in a file and print all the lines

Tags: python-3.x

I have a output in a file(/tmp/file) and want to write a code to get matching lines before and after the lines.Below is the file in (/tmp/file)

```
insert: ser.apac.prd.0000.box.ab1 job_type: BOX

start_times: "06:50"

insert: ser.apac.prd.0010.box.ab1 job_type: BOX

start_times: "07:50"

insert: ser.apac.prd.0020.box.ab1 job_type: BOX

start_times: "08:50"

insert: ser.apac.prd.0030.box.ab1 job_type: BOX

start_times: "09:50"

insert: ser.apac.prd.0040.box.ab1 job_type: CMD

start_times: "10:50"
```

And I what I get output  as below.Basically it should ignore the lines when it finds "job_type: CMD"

```
insert: ser.apac.prd.0000.box.ab1 job_type: BOX

start_times: "06:50"

insert: ser.apac.prd.0010.box.ab1 job_type: BOX

start_times: "07:50"

insert: ser.apac.prd.0020.box.ab1 job_type: BOX

start_times: "08:50"

insert: ser.apac.prd.0030.box.ab1 job_type: BOX

start_times: "09:50"
```

Below is my code and the output I am getting from the code:

```py
    with open('/tmp/file','r') as f:
    
       for file in f:
           if 'insert_job' and 'BOX' in file :
               print(file)
```

Below is output from the above code but its not giving me the output I want. Basically its missing the line start_times

```
insert: ser.apac.prd.0000.box.ab1 job_type: BOX

insert: ser.apac.prd.0010.box.ab1 job_type: BOX

insert: ser.apac.prd.0020.box.ab1 job_type: BOX

insert: ser.apac.prd.0030.box.ab1 job_type: BOX
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value)

Comment: [`if 'insert_job' in file and 'BOX' in file:`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value)

Comment: While that is part of the problem, it still does not return the lists for state_times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two potential opportunities to address.

**First:** (as pointed out by @0stone0 is your compound `if` statement does not function as you hoped. See: [How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value)

**Second:** In order to match the `start_times` rows with their corresponding `job_type` rows, you likely want to process the rows in batches of 4. See: [How do I split a list into equally-sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-i-split-a-list-into-equally-sized-chunks)

Putting both parts together, you can likely get the result you seek via:

```py
with open("infile.txt", "r") as file_in:
    rows = list(file_in)

results = [
    "".join(rows[index:index+4])
    for index in range(0, len(rows), 4)
    if "job_type: BOX" in rows[index]
]

print("".join(results))
```

**Addendum:**

It appears like you want the results to be rows like:

```
/*--- ser.apac.prd.0000.box.ab1 ---/* insert: ser.apac.prd.0000.box.ab1 job_type: BOX start_times: "06:50"
```

In order to do that, we can tweek the code slightly and use a traditional `for` loop that does much of the same work as the prior comprehension.

```py
with open("infile.txt", "r") as file_in:
    rows = list(file_in)

for index in range(0, len(rows), 4):
    if "job_type: BOX" not in rows[index]:
        continue

    content = rows[index].strip()
    name = content.split(" ")[1]
    start_time = rows[index+2].strip()
    print(f"/*--- {name} ---*/ {content} {start_time}")
```

This would produce a result like:

```
/*--- ser.apac.prd.0000.box.ab1 ---*/ insert: ser.apac.prd.0000.box.ab1 job_type: BOX start_times: "06:50"
/*--- ser.apac.prd.0010.box.ab1 ---*/ insert: ser.apac.prd.0010.box.ab1 job_type: BOX start_times: "07:50"
/*--- ser.apac.prd.0020.box.ab1 ---*/ insert: ser.apac.prd.0020.box.ab1 job_type: BOX start_times: "08:50"
/*--- ser.apac.prd.0030.box.ab1 ---*/ insert: ser.apac.prd.0030.box.ab1 job_type: BOX start_times: "09:50"
```

Comment: Hi JonSG , Thanks for an update I almost got what I want for your suggestion. For each line there is a comment as well which I wanted to print along with your about suggestion.Out should be like the below one:

Comment: /* ----------------- ser.apac.prd.0000.box.ab1 ----------------- */

insert: ser.apac.prd.0000.box.ab1 job_type: BOX
start_times: "06:50"

 /* ----------------- ser.apac.prd.0010.box.ab1 ----------------- */
insert: ser.apac.prd.0010.box.ab1 job_type: BOX
start_times: "07:50"

 /* ----------------- ser.apac.prd.0020.box.ab1 ----------------- */
insert: ser.apac.prd.0020.box.ab1 job_type: BOX
start_times: "08:50"

 /* ----------------- ser.apac.prd.0030.box.ab1 ----------------- */
insert: ser.apac.prd.0030.box.ab1 job_type: BOX
start_times: "09:50"

Comment: Many thanks .It worked.